# interior point of a triangle, equal perimeters

Tags: geometry

Let $P$ be an interior point of $\triangle ABC$. Line $AP$ meets $BC$ in $A'$, line $BP$ meets $AC$ in $B'$. Assume that $p(AA'B')=p(BB'A')$. Prove that $p(PA'C)=p(PB'C)$, where $p(XYZ)$ is the perimeter of $\triangle XYZ$.

I'm interested in a geometrical solution, I found this problem on Russian forum, with an ugly computational solution.

Comment: have you a link from this forum?

Comment: I think you have made a mistake somewhere: imagine you keep points $B, C, P, A'$ fixed, and you move $A$ along $PA'$. Then the perimeter of $\triangle PB'C$ changes, but the perimeter of $\triangle PA'C$ is fixed, and so they cannot be equal.

Comment: doesn't the move of $A$ affect the assumption?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT AND COMMENT**.-You have $$BA'+A'B'+BB'=AA'+A'B'+AB'\iff BA'+BB'=AA'+AB'\cdots (*)$$ Note that this means that the points $A$ and $B$ are in an ellipse whose focal points are the points $A'$ and $B'$ (the sum of the corresponding distances is constant by definition).

You need to prove that (similarly for  $A$ and $B$)
 $$PA'+A'C+PC=PB'+B'C+PC\iff PA'+A'C=PB'+B'C \cdots (**)$$
Let $\left(\dfrac xa \right)^2+\left(\dfrac yb \right)^2=1$ be the ellipse with focal points $B'=(-c,0)$ and $A'=(c,0)$.

Every pair of points  $A$ and $B$ in the ellipse  satisfies $(*)$ but the intersection Q of the lines $\overline{AA'}$ and $\overline{BB'}$ in general does not satisfy $(**)$. You have to calculate $P$ in order $(**)$ becomes true.

[image]

So, consider points $A=(x_1,y_1)$ and $B=(x_2,y_2)$ in the ellipse which determines the lines $\overline{AA'}$ and $\overline{BB'}$ whose intersection is the point $P=(x,y)$ with $x=\dfrac{(y_2x_1-y_2c+y_1x_2+y_1c)c}{(y_1+y_2)c+y_1x_2-y_2x_x}$ and $y=\dfrac{y_1(x-c)}{x_1-c}$ or, if you want,
$y=\dfrac{y_2(x+c)}{x_2+c}$.

Besides the lines $\overline{AB'}$ and $\overline{BA'}$ determine the vertix $C$ by intersection. You have now an example of triangle $\triangle{ABC}$ in which you can do the corresponding calculations for suitable $A,B$ and $P$.

**I stop here my comment that only aspires to justify in something what you qualify as "ugly computational solution"** (I doubt there is a beautiful one: the Russians love hard calculations to train their future mathematicians).

Comment: Yes, at some point even complex numbers were involved there, but it's principally the same brute-force argument I saw.
You're also absolutely right with your last sentence, but unusual things happen sometimes.

Comment: @tong_nor: I believe that brute-force is when there are few possibilities and they are examined one by one, or when an algorithm is previously established but the corresponding calculation is arduous, which is why it is done in separate parts. I use it many times. How do you plan to respond to dtldarek's comment? Greetings.